# Upturn animations - scrolling animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, jquery-animate

I am working on a website that I would like to change pictures on scroll. The home page will have one image, and as the user scrolls down, the image will switch through about 10 images to look like there is a seamless change. I have been looking at different websites that do similar things, and I really love the way the buildings pop up on https://www.teamupturn.com/ .

Does anyone have any ideas of how to get started? I am trying to find a good library that will let me time the transitions so that they occur really quickly? I am using PNG images right now.

Comment: Well, upturn uses `Velocity.js`, you can start by reading the documentation there. http://velocityjs.org/

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: http://stackoverflow.com/help, then read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.